# Use ng-if with ng-include to recreate scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, angular-ng-if

I have an `ng-include` inside of an `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-show="tab.active">
  <div ng-include="tab.url" class="no-padding no-margin"></div>
</div>
```

I only want the contents loaded into the DOM if the user clicks on the tab, so I am using an `ng-if` around the `ng-include`:

```
<div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-show="tab.active">
    <div ng-if="tab.loaded">
        <div ng-include="tab.url" class="no-padding no-margin"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This part is working fine. However, I have one tab that requires dynamic content, so each time a user clicks on the tab, I need the scope for that controller to be recreated.

Based on my understanding, I can also use `ng-if` to remove/recreate DOM elements. According to the `ng-if` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf):

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree
>   based on an {expression}

...

> when an element is removed using ngIf its scope is destroyed and a new
>   scope is created when the element is restored

I've added the code to set the `loaded` property of the dynamic tab to false which should remove it's contents from the DOM.

I then set it back to true, so that the scope is recreated, but I cannot get the scope to be created again.

Is my approach correct, or is there something besides `ng-if` that I can use for my purpose.

Comment: Any way for you to provide a plunkr / jsfiddle with the described behavior? My guess is that your scope, while being recreated, isn't populated the way you expect. Hard to tell without more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to "recreate" the scope? If the attribute of `ngInclude` changes in the scope, the other page will be included and will recompile all the html. Please describe why you need to do that as the reason could be wrong.

Otherwise, indeed having `ngIf` evaluate to false will remove the element. But only if it is not set to true immediately after, as angular only refresh the DOM (your HTML) when it has the opportunity to do so, i.e. after the current synchronous block of code.

This will not have any effect:

```
$scope.theTab.loaded = false;
$scope.theTab.loaded = true;
// Now Angular enter a digest cycle and see that theTab.loaded has not changed.
```

This will:

```
$scope.theTab.loaded = false;
// $timeout will wait for a digest cycle before executing the code
// Angular will remove the tab from the DOM
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.theTab.loaded = true;
  // Here a second digest cycle happen, angular will put the tab back into the DOM
});
```

Comment: Glad that worked. However it is not encouraged to do that as you may experience graphic glitches (when the element disappear and then comes back). There may be a better way to handle your issue. But if you're good with this it's all right.